# Set OpenGL ES version on Android (NDK)

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-manifest, android-ndk

I'm following these [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#glEsVersion) and trying to set OpenGL version to 1.1. But when I call `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` in my C code it always returns me

> OpenGL ES-CM 1.0

I believe I should specify version when I create context (or surface) but i can't find any API for this.

I'm also getting such kind of errors:

> 08-09 13:47:13.642: ERROR/libEGL(567): called unimplemented OpenGL ES
>   API

which also proves that OpenGL ES 1.0 is used instead of 1.1.

Edit: I should note that on device everything is OK. The problem exists only on emulator (tested on platforms 2.2 and 2.3.3)

Edit2: tested on HTC Wildfire with Android 2.2.1 and it also shows me OpenGL  version 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emulator only implements 1.0, so that's to be expected. You end up getting whichever version the hardware (or emulator) supports.

In the manifest you only specify what version of GLES your app requires. From the manifest guide:

> Declared  elements are informational only, meaning that
>   the Android system itself does not check for matching feature support
>   on the device before installing an application.

I should note that the emulator does implement most 1.1 features such as VBO support, so you should be ok to test your application on it anyway by making some small changes.

Comment: And you only see 1.0 on the wildfire, because it only supports 1.0:it uses the same pixelflinger / android gles software implementation as it doesn't have a gpu.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify version when you create context,
And in fact, there is a way to do that:

```
const EGLint attribList[] = {EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 3, EGL_NONE};
context = eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, config, EGL_NO_CONTEXT, attribList);
```

Take care of the `attribList`, this is the parameter you specify OpenGL ES version in.